# VSCode Error when starting remote dev containers

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, containers

When I try to open a remote docker container in VS Code it gives the below error:

```
[488 ms] Start: Run: docker build -f c:\Users\RYZEN\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.117.0\scripts\volumeBootstrap.Dockerfile -t vsc-volume-bootstrap c:\Users\RYZEN\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.117.0\scripts
[569 ms] Error: Unable to start terminal process: CreateProcess failed
        at new WindowsPtyAgent (c:\Users\RYZEN\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar\node-pty\lib\windowsPtyAgent.js:77:36)
        at new WindowsTerminal (c:\Users\RYZEN\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar\node-pty\lib\windowsTerminal.js:50:24)
        at Object.spawn (c:\Users\RYZEN\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar\node-pty\lib\index.js:28:12)
        at c:\Users\RYZEN\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.117.0\dist\extension.js:1:5211
        at async Object.t.runCommand (c:\Users\RYZEN\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.117.0\dist\extension.js:1:8512)
        at async c:\Users\RYZEN\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.117.0\dist\extension.js:1:118726
        at async Object.D [as cloneAndBuildRepository] (c:\Users\RYZEN\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.117.0\dist\extension.js:1:118585)
        at async Object.t.openDockerfileRepoDevContainer (c:\Users\RYZEN\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.117.0\dist\extension.js:1:165567)
```

[image]

My system:

- Windows 10 Professional
- Docker Desktop 2.3.0.2

Has anyone encountered this issue and what are the possible solutions, please advise.

Comment: Hello, I hit this problem today after a docker update. Killing all running containers and restarting VS Code corrected this issue for me.

Comment: I also had done a docker update before this issue surfaced, and also I noticed that this was mostly happening with the sample containers that Microsoft provides. If I create a dev container config and start a remote container it works fine. Created this issue (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97677) and it was closed with the comments "/duplicate microsoft/vscode-remote-release#2975
Fixed with 0.117.1 of the Remote-Containers extension."